# Deleting messages sometimes fails silently

Tags: telethon

I am using Telethon in a Quart app.

This function is called to delete messages from chats based on a list of message ids.

```
async def delete_msg(entity, msg_ids):
    client = await setup_tg_client()   # Function that sets up Telegram client with phone no., api ip and hash
    try:
        await client.connect()
        if await client.is_user_authorized():
            await client.delete_messages(entity, msg_ids)
            await client.disconnect()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error when deleting msgs: {e}", flush=True)
```

Every now and then (seemingly at random), deleting messages fails silently. Everything after the function is executed and I don't see anything in the app logs.

Could it be that I'm expecting `delete_messages` to throw an exception when it actually doesn't?
Is it something related to Telegram, beyond the scope of Telethon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following codes to delete.

`Code: async for message in client.iter_messages('chat id'): if message.id == xxxx: await message.delete()`